# Calculating the difference of the factors of a semiprime

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let there be a semiprime
$N=p q$
where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

If the value of $N$ is given, is there any way to calculate the value of $(p-q)$. If not exactly then approximately ?

**Update :** Anyway of calculating the upper bound and lower bound in which $p-q$ will lie ?

Thanks

Comment: Obviously calculating $p-q$ is equivalent to factoring $N$.  And you have asked essentially the same question twice: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727635/approximate-the-difference-between-the-factors-of-a-semiprime

Answer (score 2):

If $pq$ and $p-q$ are known, then so is $(p+q)^2=(p-q)^2+4pq$, and hence so is $p+q$. Therefore determining $p-q$ is equivalent to determining $p$ and $q$.

Comment: I mean at least we can calculate the lower bound of $p+q$ by assuming that a quadratic equation has two roots namely $p$ and $q$ and after solving it we can find that $p+q > 2*sqrt(N)$

Comment: True, $p+q\geq 2\sqrt{pq}$ by the AM-GM inequality. I don't think that gets you much closer to finding $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Just looking for any new ways to get a better result.

Comment: One can place lower bounds on $|p−q|$ using Fermat factorization and upper bounds on $|p−q|$ using trial division (or other ways to find small factors, e.g. Pollard-rho), but generally, the bounds are so loose compared to the possible range that it would be a stretch to call those "approximations". This was said by @ErickWong


Can someone help me out by telling me how can I exactly place these bounds ?

Comment: @ApoorvaSingh Answered.  But the bounds I'm talking about are analogous to narrowing the search for a real number in the interval $[0,1]$ to the smaller interval $[0.0001, 0.9999]$.  As I said, I would hesitate to call that an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Lower bounds on $|p-q|$ are equivalent to ruling out the existence of factorizations with $p$ and $q$ close together.

Fermat factorization (assuming $N$ is odd, but the question is trivial if $N$ is an even semiprime) looks for solutions to $N = x^2 - y^2$, since any factorization $N=pq$ corresponds to $x= \frac{p+q}{2}, y = \frac{p-q}{2}$.  It's easy to see that making $p-q$ small is equivalent to making $x$ as small as possible.  So you can step through possible values of $x$ (starting with $\lceil\sqrt{N}\rceil$), which gives lower bounds for $x$ and in turn lower bounds for $y$.  These aren't very strong bounds but they are initially better (for the same amount of effort) than trial division counting down from $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$.  See example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method#Fermat.27s_and_trial_division

Upper bounds on $|p-q|$ are equivalent to ruling out small prime divisors of $N$.  This is literally trial division, but it can also be done (albeit probabilistically in most cases that I know of) by using more advanced factoring methods such as [Pollard rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) or [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization) which perform well when there is a small prime divisor.